# Load observations from a file and count them [Matlab]

Tags: matlab

I want to load all observations of X from a file Var, and get the total number of observations in matlab. I do not know if the observations are in vector or array form.
This is my attempt:

```
    % Load observations of variable X
load Var
% Get total number of observations
count = 0;
L = length(___);
for i = L
    count = count + 1;
end
Ntot = count;
```

I don't know what to pass in as a parameter to the length function. I tried Var but didn't work. It's abstract because file Var is hidden.

Comment: Give `clear` and then `load Var` at the MATLAB command prompt. Then give `whos`. This will print a list of defined variables, all of which would have come from loading the file. Now you'll know what the name of the variable is that you need to use.

Comment: Note that `for i = L` will iterate exactly once, with `i` equal to `L`. You want to do `for i = 1:L` to iterate over the elements of `L`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you for your feedback. Knowing the defined variables were not needed. I was iterating wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear the type of the variables stored in the `Var` file, nevertheless, as a general approach you can use the [matfile](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.matfile.html) to get the informatino about the variables stored in a ".mat" file.

Since `matfile` returns a MAT-file object as a struct, you can exploit the dynaminc definition of  the struct filed names to get the info about the variable.

The folowing provides an example with three arrays stored in the `Var.mat` file; you should be able to adapt the example to your specific mat file

The comments in the code should describe how the code works.

```
% Define some variables
a=1:3
b=1:6
c=1:9

% Save them in a mat file
save("Var.mat","a","b","c")

% Create a MAT-file object
var_info=matfile("Var.mat")

% Retrieve the information about the variables saved in the mat file
var_names=fieldnames(var_info);

% Remove the first entry which ciontains the information about the Properties of the mat fle
var_names(1)=[];

% Get the number of the variables stored in the mat file
number_of_var=length(var_names)

% Initialize the counter
count=0;

% Loop through the var_info struct
% Exploit the dynamic definition of the names of the struct's fileds
for i=1:number_of_var
   % Count the length of the variables
   n=length(var_info.(var_names{i}));
   count=count+n;
   fprintf('The variable %s is an array of %d elements\n',var_names{i},n)
end
fprintf('The total is %d\n',count)
```

Comment: Two things: (1) `length` is not the number of elements, it is `max(size)`. You want to use `numel` instead. (2) Accessing the variable through the object returned by `matfile` loads the variable in memory. It defeats the purpose of this object. You can get the variable size without loading it with `size(var_info,var_names{i})`. If you’re loading all variables anyway you might as well use `load` instead of `matfile` and simplify your code.

Comment: Oh, you can use `var_names = who(var_info)` to get the list of variables names in the file.